# Babel not converting TypeScript in Expo

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, expo, babeljs

I'm trying to upload Cloud Functions to my Firebase console. My app runs fine on Expo but when attempting to upload, I think my code tries compiling and throws this error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

<root_project_directory>\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\warnOnce.js:15
const warnedKeys: { [string]: boolean } = {};
      ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1067:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1115:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\justi\CodingProjects\ChinesePoker\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js:14:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
```

This seems to be an issue with Babel not recognizing typescript and converting it to javascript but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried installing `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` and `@babel/preset-typescript` separately but neither worked. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Relevant Files**

`babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      "babel-preset-expo",
    ]
  };
};
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.3.5",
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "firebaseui": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: What makes you think Babel is being invoked at all?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, when attempting to upload Cloud Functions it requires a build which invokes Babel. Everything I've read on the issue suggests it stems from Javascript compilers (I've seen many people have this problem with Jest). There's nothing wrong with the statement `const warnedKeys: { [string]: boolean } = {};`, it's just Typescript so it seems to be an issue in converting that Typescript to Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. This is an error thrown when you attempt to require('react-native') in node. Removing this statement fixed the problem.